# Validation rule fires while criteria are not met

Tags: validation-rule

I have following validation rule.

> AND(
>
> ISCHANGED( Inhuurpartij__c ),
>
> OR(
>
> NOT(ISPICKVAL( Job_Contract_Type__c ,"External")),
>
> NOT(ISPICKVAL( Job_Contract_Type__c ,"Freelance"))
>
> )   )

I tried to write it all ways I know but it is still fired, when I try to change `Inhuurpartij` field, while `Job Contract Type` is *External* or *Freelance*. Anyone any idea?

Comment: Last condition is always true. If you write OR(NOT(X=a), NOT(X=b)), and X is a, then second will be true => result is true. if X is b, then first condition under OR is true, and result is true as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
AND(

ISCHANGED( Inhuurpartij__c ),

NOT( OR(

ISPICKVAL( Job_Contract_Type__c ,"External"),

ISPICKVAL( Job_Contract_Type__c ,"Freelance")

) ) )
```

In your original validation rule, the Job_Contract_Type__c was always going to be either not one of the values or not the other, so it would always evaluate to true.